# Putting multiple container views inside paged UIScrollView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIScrollView` in a `UIViewController`. Now I want to add multiple container views to this scroll view. The size of each container view is same as that of scroll view,.i.e, one container view fills the scroll view basically. Now I will add multiple container views to this scroll view by setting frames of container views and changing contentSize of scroll views.

This creates a problem in rotation. When the device is rotated form portrait to landscape, then 2 container views are shown at once. I want these container views to be resized on rotation. One way by which I can do this is to update the frames of all of my container views (added to scroll view so far) when the device is rotated.

But I want to use auto-layout constraints to handle this. But I am not able to get what constraints to use when adding containers to scroll view.

Comment: Have you tried to use a UICollectionView or is there a specific reason you're using a UIScrollView?

Comment: There is no special reason of using scroll views. I just wanted to have horizontally paged views with each view covering whole screen in both portrait and landscape orientations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a UICollectionView instead. Set the size of the collectionView to match the display and set the cell size to be virtually the same as the collectionview. Put auto layout constraints around the collection view to keep the distance between its edges and the superview constant.

Use the CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate Method

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to control the size of your cell. Here is an example from one of my own projects.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
    if (iPhone5) return CGSizeMake(470.f, 150.f);
    else return CGSizeMake(380.f, 150.f);
}
if (iPhone5) return CGSizeMake(270.f, 325.f);
else return CGSizeMake(272.f, 390.f);
}
```

Put your container views inside the cell and apply auto layout constraints from the edges of the container to the cell.

Finally, override the collection view layout and set the scroll direction to horizontal.

Comment: Can you please tell how can we apply auto layout constraint to the `UICollectionViewCell` so that the whole cell's size is changed on rotation. As far as I know, cell takes its size and on rotation same size is kept unless we change its size explicitly.

Comment: The method you are using is kind of manually giving the frame by doing calculations on rotation which I wanted to avoid. This would work but I wanted to do fully using autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone landing here for the same question, there is this nice post https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/ about handling elements inside a UIScrollView while using autolayout. It is totally worth reading.

A brief summary:

1. The UIScrollView should only have ONE child view.
2. Besides adding the constraints you normally will, consider that you require a EQUAL WIDTH constraint between your scrollview's superview (the main view) and your scrollview's only child (the content view).
3. Depending on each case, you may probably need little adjustments through code and that's fine.